# Android saving xml data

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xHeo.png)i have data that takes the following relational form

```
<data>
<array name="group_name">
        <string name="x">3</string>
        <string name="y">4</string>
        <string name="z">5</string>
    </array>
    <array name="group_2_name">
        <string name="x">6</string>
        <string name="y">7</string>
        <string name="z">8</string>
    </array>
</data>
```

How do I save such data in a way I can get it back for use easily? I know I can't save it on strings.xml. Do I use an array list?

how do I make the data relational with that? The logic flow is that the group_name is saved from an edittext widget and x,y and z are selected from different NumberPickers. 
On click button save, I want to save the data in a relational format. 
On a different android fragment, I want to display a spinner populated with only group_names and when I select a spinner item, I want to display the strings it holds as x,y and z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many of those groups you will have?

If you have a big number of those groups and you want to persist your data, I'd do a simple `SQLiteDatabase` to hold this data. Check out [THIS](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) tutorial on how to do it.

```
                 MY_DATA_TABLE
group_name     x_value     y_value    z_value
```

If you do NOT need this data to be persistent and you have a small number of groups (just the two you mentioned) - you can get by with storing some data structure in a Singleton somewhere - for example

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> myData
```

You'll save data like this:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(3);
values.put(x_value);
values.put(y_value);
values.put(z_value);
myData.put(groupName1, values);
```

Comment: I'll have as many as the user desires. As many as the user names from the editText widget

Comment: Do you need it persistent or not, meaning do you need this data to be saved after the user kills the app and starts it again?

Comment: Yes, that would be convenient

Comment: Totally go for the SQLite database solution than! Check the link in my answer for the whole step-by-step tutorial by Google.

Comment: And don't be surprised - it might seem like a lot of work initially, but the efforts definitely pay off quickly :)